# Vee validation is not working inside the <b-form-input> tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

Below is my code. In the addEmployee.vue file, fields are there. Firstname , Middlename , Lastname. Among the three fields "Firtname & Lastname" has noraml  tag. But "Middlename" has  tag. Vee-validate "required" validation is working for the normal input tag fields but it's not working for Middlename field. What is the reason for this?

addEmployee.vue

```
  <template>
 <b-card>
    <h4 slot="header" class="card-title">Employee</h4>
        <b-row>
            <b-col sm="3">
              <b-form-group>
                <label for="name">First Name </label>
                <input type="text" id=""  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" v-validate="'required|Name'" name="Firstname">
                        <span v-show="errors.has('Firstname')" class="is-danger">{{ errors.first('Firstname') }}</span>
               </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
            <b-col sm="3">
              <b-form-group>
                <label for="name">Middle Name </label>
               <b-form-input type="text" id="" placeholder="Enter your name" v-validate="'required|Name'" name="Middlename"> 
                  <span v-show="errors.has('Middlename')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Middlename') }}</span></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
             <b-col sm="3">
              <b-form-group>
                <label for="name">Last Name </label>
                <input type="text" id=""  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your middle name" v-validate="'required|Name'" name="Lastname">
                        <span v-show="errors.has('Lastname')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Lastname') }}</span>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" @click="validateForm">
 </b-card>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

export default {
  name: 'addEmpl'
},
   methods: {
    validateForm() {
    this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
    if(!result){
    alert('not submitted')
    return
  }
  alert('submitted')
}).catch(() => {
});
   }
}
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.is-danger{
  color:  RED;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use lodash that's how i solved my problem [refer this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997178/why-my-wysiwyg-editor-works-so-slow-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 1):

you have to close b-form-input before span ;

```
<b-form-group>
                <label for="name">Middle Name </label>
               <b-form-input type="text" id="" placeholder="Enter your name" v-validate="'required|Name'" name="Middlename"> 
                  <span v-show="errors.has('Middlename')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Middlename') }}</span></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
              </b-form-group>
```

become :

```
<b-form-group>
                <label for="name">Middle Name </label>
               <b-form-input type="text" id="" placeholder="Enter your name" v-validate="'required|Name'" name="Middlename"> </b-form-input>
                  <span v-show="errors.has('Middlename')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Middlename') }}</span>
              </b-form-group>
```

delete duplicated /b-form-group also (not critical) ,
now it works :)

Comment: No. It's not working. I have changed like how you said. `<b-form-group><b-form-input type="text" id="" placeholder="Enter your name" v-validate="'required|Name'" name="Middlename"> </b-form-input>
                  <span v-show="errors.has('Middlename')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Middlename') }}</span> </b-form-group>`

Comment: it works for me, try to test with 'required' without |Name

Comment: @Mgasmi.Yeash it's working only when 'on change' of the field. I have to enter the value first, then If I removed the value, 'required error message' gets displayed. But for the other fields, error message displays when on blur the field itself